# what's the different between typeof and mapped type [key in keyof typeof]?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

here is a dummyObj variable

```
const dummyObj = {
   prop1:'value1',
   prop2:'value2',
   prop3:['value3']
}
```

what's the different between this two types?

```
type DummyObj1 = typeof dummyObj;
```

```
type DummyObj2 = { [key in Exclude<keyof typeof dummyObj, 'prop3'>]: string } 
& { prop3: Array<string> };
```

I check vscode and it gives me this

```
type DummyObj1 = {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: string[];
}
```

```
type DummyObj2 = {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
} & {
    prop3: Array<string>;
}
```

I am not sure where the different is.

Comment: declare a variable of type `DummyObj1` and try to assign to it a value which is of type `DummyObj2`.

Comment: They are different forms of essentially the same type; it's like asking what the difference is between "5 + 2" and "7".  Conceptually there is no difference, although they are represented in different ways.  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I am not sure which one is more maintainable or more widely used? or there is no difference so I can choose DummyObj1 since it's more readable?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Why would you want to put in an intersection in a type if you don't need it?

Comment: I don't have enough information to tell you which one to use; there is currently no difference, but if you ever edit the code to change how `dummyObj` is defined then there could be a difference.  Without a [mre] that shows an intended use case, anything I say here would be conjecture or opinion, neither of which are really appropriate for Stack Overflow.